# How to change the init directory for an Azure WebApp

Tags: php, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an PHP application running on a Linux Azure WebApp service, with the following structure:

```
|- includes/*
|- public_heml/
|--- /index.php
|--- /index_Routes.php
|--- /index_Routes.php
|--- /phpinfo.php
|- /src/*
|- /vendor/*
```

I must keep this structure because of the framework the application was built.

The problem is that my Azure WebApp is looing for `index.php` on the root of my application, but my `index.php` is located under `public_html/` directory.

How can I configure that using the Azure Portal?

Comment: So, can you offer what OS you are base on? Windows or Linux

Comment: @BowmanZhu linux

Comment: Hi, things works on my side. You can have a try whether it can also works on yours.

Comment: Have you try my solution? is it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `Linux OS`, you have no choose to configure that using Azure Portal.

**Solution:**

**1.Create a `.htaccess` file under the root directory.**

**`.htaccess` file:**

```
DirectoryIndex public_html/index.php
```

**2.Restart your web app and wait for minutes.**

---

**This is the structure of my web app:**

[image]

**Success:**

[image]

Let me know if you have more doubts.

Comment: Worked like a charm